# How to use env variable in Docker RUN command under "SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C" ]"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

If I use env var "TEMP_DIR" in the file path like below:

```
"RUN $env:TEMP_DIR\BuildTools2017\vs_buildtools_2017.exe..."
```

or

```
 "RUN $TEMP_DIR\BuildTools2017\vs_buildtools_2017.exe..."
```

Then, building will run into error:

> "The system cannot find the path specified."

Why? How should I avoid using the hardcoded `"C:\temp"` in the file path, thanks.

**Dockerfile to install the build tools for VS 2017:**

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-windowsservercore

ARG version

ENV TEMP_DIR="c:/temp"

SHELL ["powershell","-NoProfile","-Command","$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; "]

# Create temp file for installers
RUN New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path $env:TEMP_DIR;

# Install Visual Studio ultimate 2012
COPY ./VS2012_ultimate "c:/temp/VS2012_ultimate"
RUN \
    Start-Process -FilePath "$env:TEMP_DIR/VS2012_ultimate/vs_ultimate.exe" - ArgumentList '/passive', '/q', '/s', '/norestart', '/noweb', '/full',  -PassThru | Wait-Process;

# Install Blend.Sdk.WPF 4.0 & 4.5
COPY ./BlendSdk "$TEMP_DIR/BlendSdk"

RUN \
    Start-Process -FilePath "$env:TEMP_DIR/BlendSdk/BlendWPFSDK_en.msi" -ArgumentList '/passive', '/norestart' -PassThru | Wait-Process; \
    Start-Process -FilePath "$env:TEMP_DIR/BlendSdk/BlendWPFSDK.msi" -ArgumentList '/passive', '/norestart' -PassThru | Wait-Process;


# Install build tool for VS 2017
SHELL ["cmd", "/S", "/C"]

COPY ./BuildTools2017 "$TEMP_DIR/BuildTools2017"

RUN C:\temp\BuildTools2017\vs_buildtools_2017.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache --noWeb --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools
 --add Microsoft.Net.Component.3.5.DeveloperTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.Windows10SDK.17763

SHELL ["powershell", "-NoProfile", "-Command", "$ErrorActionPreference = 'Stop'; $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'; "]
```

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: "The system cannot find the path specified."

Comment: Sorry, I'm not on a Windows machine right now so I can't test this, but have you tried writing `%TEMP_DIR%` instead of `$TEMP_DIR`? That should be the right syntax for using environment variables with cmd.exe.

Answer (score 0):

Windows exposes `%TEMP%` environment variable:

```
RUN %TEMP%\BuildTools2017\vs_buildtools_2017.exe --quiet --wait --norestart --nocache --noWeb --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.ManagedDesktopBuildTools --add Microsoft.VisualStudio.Workload.VCTools
```